# Сложение стобликом в различных СС

Tags: c#

Нужно реализовать сложение столбиком в системах счисления до 16.
Не могу понять как связать сложение столбиком с системами счисления и как добавлять единицу при переносе.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Calculator
{
    public class Addition
    {
        public void OutputAddition()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Введите первое число для сложения");
            string firstValue = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Введите второе число для сложения");
            string secondValue = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Введите систему счисления в которой эти числа");
            int notation = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine(firstValue);
            Console.WriteLine("+");
            Console.WriteLine(secondValue);
            Console.WriteLine("--------------");

            var a = firstValue.Select(ch => ch - '0').ToArray();
            var b = secondValue.Select(ch => ch - '0').ToArray();
            var res = Sum(a, b,notation);
            var result = res.Reverse();
            foreach(int values in result)
            {
                Console.Write(values);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\n");
        }

        private static int[] Sum(int[] a, int[] b, int notation)
        {
            var res = new List<int>();

            var rest = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < Math.Max(a.Length, b.Length); i++)
            {
                var n1 = i < a.Length ? a[i] : 0;
                var n2 = i < b.Length ? b[i] : 0;
                var sum = n1 + n2 + rest;
                res.Add(sum % notation);
                rest = sum / notation;
            }

            if (rest > 0)
                res.Add(rest);

            return res.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://gitlab.com/IlyaKvashnin/Calculator2

Comment: @AlexF вот что получается, не знаю как это связать и остатки переносить

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> как связать сложение столбиком с системами счисления

Если при сложении сумма цифр больше либо равна основанию системы счисления, нужно перенести единицу в следующий разряд, а из суммы цифр вычесть основание системы счисления. Операцию сложения следует выполнять от младшего разряда к старшему. Готово, связал.

Математика, 2-й класс средней школы, сложение столбиком. Всё что туда добавилось, это то что основание может быть не 10. Остальное в точности как у второклашек.